# make SelectionColor transparent in mx:datagrid

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, flex3

I am using a mx:DataGrid component in my flex application. I showing a grid like this:

[image]

I want to change the selected Blue color to transparent. I am using following code:

```
<mx:DataGrid id="dg" dataProvider="{arrDg}" width="100%" height="100%" 
    draggableColumns="false" rowCount="{arrDg.length}" click="dgClickHandler(event)" 
    variableRowHeight="true" resizableColumns="false" sortableColumns="false" 
    selectionColor="#00000000" verticalScrollPolicy="off">
```

But this is changing the color to black instead of transparent.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Edit[**

Oops, didn't notice you had 8 zero's in that color. Flash doesn't support RGBA (or color values with alpha/transparency).

**[end edit]**

If you do not want any highlight at all to be shown on selection, try setting the [selectable](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/listClasses/ListBase.html#selectable) property of the (mx) `DataGrid` to `false`. It seems you have a click handler, turning off selection is likely to prevent your click handler from doing it's job :(

If you do want some sort of selection indicator, but say, want to modify the alpha (transparency) of the selection color, that style setting does not exist (ie: there is no "selectionAlpha" style).  You would have to create a custom data grid class to do that.

Comment: setting "selectable" false did the trick and i also removed the click handler.

Answer (score 0):

If you need the `mx:DataGrid` to be selectable but also want the selection color not to affect the color of your cells/rows you can use this approach:

Extend `DataGrid` an override the function `drawSelectionIndicator` and leave the content of the function empty (you may also be interested in overriding the `drawHighlightIndicator` function)

```
public class CustomRowColorDataGrid extends DataGrid
{
    public function CustomRowColorDataGrid()
    {
        super();
    }

    override protected function drawSelectionIndicator(indicator:Sprite, x:Number, y:Number, w:Number, h:Number, color:uint, itemRenderer:IListItemRenderer):void
    {
        //If you want a rectangle arround the selected row use call this method 
        //Rectangle(indicator,x,y,0xFF9900, 2,h) ;
    }

    override protected function drawHighlightIndicator(indicator:Sprite, x:Number, y:Number, w:Number, h:Number, color:uint, itemRenderer:IListItemRenderer):void
    {
        Rectangle(indicator,x,y,highlight, 2,h) ;
    }

    private function Rectangle(indicator:Sprite, xx:int, yy:int,colorBorde:uint,grosor:int, h:int):void
    {
        var g:Graphics ;
        var w:int ;

        w = this.width - this.verticalScrollBar.width-1 ;

        g = Sprite(indicator).graphics;
        g.clear();
        g.lineStyle(grosor,colorBorde) ;
        g.drawRect(0,1,w-grosor,h-grosor) ;

        indicator.x = xx;
        indicator.y = yy;
    }       
}
```